Why does I have just the last day of GA4 in my BigQuery data?
Data received daily
I've just started using BigQuery because the new GA4 interface is uncomfortable so I'm trying to use BigQuery.
I would like a dataset of all the days. I just get the previous day.
All is checked in the link between GA4/BigQuery.
My data in GA4 has a long lifetime.

There is no word "datas" in the English language. "Data" is both singular and plural at the same time

I've found the filter that was limiting it to just the last day:

Altering that filter allows it to show more data.
